# jQuery change html content during long script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have long jQuery script, which gets near 5 minutes.
During this script page is absolutely blocked.
Is it possible to make changes on page during this event?

Comment: when you say changes, do you mean from the mentioned script or another? What exactly is the first script doing?

Comment: From mentioned script, what it doing is explained below (look comments below first answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the jQuery is performing synchronous operations then no, JavaScript is a single-threaded environment meaning that until your script completes the event loop is blocked. If the operations are asynchronous (e.g., AJAX requests, things wrapped in Promises/callbacks) then it would be *possible* to provided the user feedback.

More importantly however, I find it hard to imagine a situation where a function would be running for 5 minutes client side, perhaps you need a better approach to whatever it is you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm running ajax in loop, each ajax gets ~2sec, on every end of loop i want to show "Remaining time", but the page is completely blocked and i can't change anything until the script finish..

Comment: Without actual code samples the best I can think of is something like this:

    var $remainingTime = $('#timer');

    var loop = function () {
      setTimeout(function () {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/path',
          success: function (data) {
            $remainingTime.text('updated text');
            if (/* more stuff to do */) {
              loop();
            }
          }
        });
      }, 2000);
    }

Just off the top of my head :)

Comment: That was exactly that what i looking for! Thanks.